# Facebook login with php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

Everything works great when I log in, I get the users id and Name, however when I click on "Logout" button, it just logs me out of facebook, nothing else happens. Button doesn't wan't to change to "Login". Why? It just ignores the else part of the statement...

```
public function fblogin() {

            require_once '../application/libraries/facebook.php';

            //Create our Application instance
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => '**********', // Facebook App ID
                'secret' => '*******************', // Facebook App Secret

            ));

            //Get User ID
            $user = $facebook->getUser();

            if (isset($user)) {
                try {

                  $me = $facebook->api("/me"); 

                } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                    $user = null;
                    echo $e-> getMessage(); 
                }

                if ($me) {

                    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
                    echo $me["id"];
                    echo $me["name"];
                    echo ("<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>");

                }

            }

            else {

                $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
                echo ("<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>");
            }


        }
```

Comment: Check what this code returns after logout `$user = $facebook->getUser();`, maybe $user still validates to true...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you add the else at the end of this fraction

```
if ($me) {

                $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
                echo $me["id"];
                echo $me["name"];
                echo ("<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>");

            } else {

            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
            echo ("<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>");
        }
```